# Only show the latest entry for each employee in a list form

Tags: ms-access

Great site!! I have found a lot of answers on here for adding features to the databases I have created as a guest just browsing the site so though it was about time I set up a proper account for myself on here, I have been making databases with access for a while now & I would like to think they are improving all the time.

I have created a quick & dirty example which has two tables, a list form & an entry form, the list form currently displays all of the records of the training table for all employees, in some of the databases I have created I would like to add a list form but I would only like it to only display the latest entry (for each user in the example)

Is there an easy way to achieve this by adding to the query or code to the form?

Example database uploaded to google drive below

[Quick & Dirty Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TCUNNjp_-6O21_VqOqwdvViLIGIuuqTJ/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `subform` instead of continuous form. For subform data source use query from tables to display latest data for each trainee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following SQL to show latest entry for each employee.

```
SELECT tblTraining.*
FROM tblTraining
WHERE (tblTraining.TrainingDate)=(select max(t2.TrainingDate)
                from tblTraining as t2
                where t2.EmployeeName = tblTraining.EmployeeName);
```

Then you can use this query as data source of subform.

Comment: @PSD2k20 Glad to know. If you found the code working then you should consider accepting the answer. Tick mark the answer.